# How to make any call to Class::function get Mock::function response

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I'm working on unit tests and trying to replace value returned by a class function which is called somewhere else that my unit test.

I started working on `Mock` object which seems to be the solution for me.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?php

namespace A;

class SomeClass
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        return 20;
    }
}

/**
 * @group DaTest
 */
class DaTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testStub()
    {
        // Create a stub for the SomeClass class.
        $stub = $this
            ->getMock('A\SomeClass', array('doSomething'))
        ;

        // Configure the stub.
        $stub
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method('doSomething')
            ->willReturn(1)
        ;

        $a = new SomeClass();

        var_dump($stub->doSomething)); // Return 1
        var_dump($a->doSomething());   // Return 20 -.-'
    }
}
```

As you can see I feel I'm forced to use the Mock to get "1" returned.
But my goal is to make any instance of `SomeClass` return 1 but only for for my unit tests.

What am I missing ?
Any idea on how I can achieve this ?

Thx.

Edit:
To show exactly what I'm trying to do I got another code which is:

```
<?php

namespace A;

class SomeClass2
{
    public function showSomething()
    {
        $class = new SomeClass();
        // Here print 20, I want it to print 1 in my unit test
        echo $class->doSomething();
    }
}
```

All I want is to get `SomeClass2::showSomething()` print 1 in my unit test and 20 when I call it in non-test environment =)

Comment: If you want to prevent original behaviour of the function, you did everything right

Comment: Well I want ```$a->doSomething()``` return "1" too, because in my case the function I want to "override" isn't called directly in my test, but in the code of some function my test call, so I can't send it mock.

Comment: Got it, the function that you want to test may not be written correctly. Let's adapt the example closer to your original code. Then it will be easier to help you

Comment: Do you get what I want to do with edit code ?

Comment: Sure. So what you need to do is inject instance of SomeClass as argument to showSomething() function. As a result you will be able to mock SomeClass

Comment: Well I was scared you would answer that, it is in an at least 10-depth function from unit test I instanciate and use the class I want to mock. I can't break whole project architecture passing class/mock as parameter between each function :/

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/php-test-helpers/php-test-helpers it may help you

Comment: I finally found a workaround and am passing my mock in parameter so I can call its function.
I can't put your answers as the one which resolved my problem :/
Do you know how I can do this ?
Maybe it's because it is on "the small response list" and not considered as a post.
You can copy paste your answer using "Answer question" so I can set this thread resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need to do is inject instance of SomeClass as argument to showSomething() function. As a result you will be able to mock SomeClass

```
<?php

namespace A;

class SomeClass2
{
    public function showSomething(SomeClass $classInstance)
    {
        echo $classInstance->doSomething();
    }
}
```